# Integrate $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^4}}$ from $0$ to $1$.

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

I'm having some difficulties doing this improper integral:

$$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^4}}\,dx$$

We have the conflictive point at $1$, but I don't know how to do this integral. I know how to solve this one:

$$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\,dx$$

but I don't know how to (or if it's possible) extrapolate this information to the other integral.

Thank you.

Comment: Isn’t that an elliptic integral?

Comment: It's possible, but in my course they haven't mentioned them.

Comment: Probably not a full solution, but did you try expanding the integrand using Generalized Binomial series, in your case with coefficient $\binom{-\frac{1}{2}}{k}$?

Comment: Isn't this equal to the inverse of a hyperbolic trig function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Applying the substitution $u=x^4$ we get $x=u^{1/4}$ and  $4x^3dx=4u^{3/4}dx=du$ and with some algebra we arrive at:

$$\frac{1}{4}\int_{0}^{1} u^{-3/4}(1-u)^{-1/2} du$$

$$=\frac{1}{4}\int_{0}^{1} u^{\frac{1}{4}-1}(1-u)^{\frac{1}{2}-1} du$$

Which can be evaluated recognizing it is a form of the beta function, and applying the beta-gamma relationship:

$$\frac{1}{4}B(\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{2})$$

$$=\frac{\frac{1}{4}\Gamma(\frac{1}{4})\Gamma(\frac{1}{2})}{\Gamma(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4})}$$

$$=\frac{\Gamma(\frac{5}{4})\sqrt{\pi}}{\Gamma(\frac{3}{4})}$$