# Compute the following sum in closed form : $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n\binom{2n}{n}}{4^{n}(2n+1)(2n-1)(4n+1)}$

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, closed-form

$$\text{Find : }\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n\binom{2n}{n}}{4^{n}(2n+1)(2n-1)(4n+1)}$$

I know that $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{2n}{n}x^{2n}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4x^{2}}}$ so $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n\binom{2n}{n}x^{2n}=\frac{2x^2}{\sqrt{1-4x^{2}}}$.

But I don't know he to complete this work because I find hypergeometric function.

Comment: Using Mathematica I get $-\frac{\pi}{8} - \frac{\sqrt{\pi}\; \Gamma(1/4)}{3 \Gamma(-1/4)}$.

Comment: The sum is given by the triple integral $$\sqrt{2}\int_0^{1/\sqrt2}\int_0^t\frac{1}{u^3}\int_0^u \frac{2v^2dv}{\sqrt{1-4v^2}}dudt$$

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the sum is also given by the hypergeometric $$\frac1{30}\,_2F_2(1/2,5/4;5/2,9/4;1)$$

Comment: @clathratus. I think that the hypergeometric function is not correct (if I am not mistaken !). Using another CAS, I had $$\frac{\pi }{24}-\frac{1}{45} \,
   _3F_2\left(\frac{5}{4},\frac{3}{2},\frac{3}{2};\frac{9}{4},\frac{5}{2};1\right)$$ which I could not simplify but which numerically is effectively what Chip Hurst gave in comments.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici you, having far more experience than me, are most likely correct

Comment: @clathratus. Please, listen the old man : we are all equal  here ! I may be right today and wrong tomorrow and same for you. Cheers :-)

Comment: @Kînan Jœd - If you don't mind me asking, I would like to know how you came across this sum? The final result is quite beautiful.

Answer (score 7):

As remarked in the OP, 
\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{2n}{n}x^{2n}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4x^{2}}}
\end{equation} 
or, by changing $x\to x/2$,
\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{4^n}\binom{2n}{n}x^{2n}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^{2}}}
\end{equation} 
We use the decomposition
\begin{equation}
\frac{n}{\left( 2n-1 \right)\left( 2n+1 \right)\left( 4n+1 \right)}=\frac{1}{12}\frac{1}{2n-1}-\frac{1}{4}\frac{1}{2n+1}+\frac{1}{3}\frac{1}{4n+1}
\end{equation} 
Then, for $\left|x\right|<1$, as the three series converge absolutely
\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{4^n}\binom{2n}{n}\frac{nx^{2n}}{\left( 2n-1 \right)\left( 2n+1 \right)\left( 4n+1 \right)}=\frac{1}{12}S_--\frac{1}{4}S_++\frac{1}{3}S_2
\end{equation} 
where
\begin{align}
S_+&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{4^n}\binom{2n}{n}\frac{1}{ 2n+1}\\
S_-&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{4^n}\binom{2n}{n}\frac{1}{2n-1}\\
S_2&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{4^n}\binom{2n}{n}\frac{1}{4n+1}
\end{align} 
With the notation
\begin{equation}
f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^{2}}}
\end{equation} 
by integrating the above series, we have
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{4^n}\binom{2n}{n}x^{2n}&=f(x)-1\\
S_+=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{4^n}\binom{2n}{n}\frac{1}{2n+1}&=\int_0^1 \left[f(x)-1\right]\,dx\\
&=\frac{\pi}{2}-1
\end{align}
A simple transformations is necessary forevaluating $S_-$:
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{4^n}\binom{2n}{n}x^{2n-2}&=\frac{f(x)-1}{x^2}\\
S_-=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{4^n}\binom{2n}{n}\frac{1}{2n-1}&=\int_0^1\frac{f(x)-1}{x^2}\,dx\\
&=1
\end{align} 
For the third term, changing $x\to x^2$ in the series before integrating 
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{4^n}\binom{2n}{n}x^{4n}&=f(x^2)-1\\
S_2=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{4^n}\binom{2n}{n}\frac{1}{4n+1}&=\int_0^1\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x^4}}-1\\
&=\frac{\Gamma(\frac{5}{4})\sqrt{\pi}}{\Gamma(\frac{3}{4})}-1\\
&=\frac{\left[\Gamma\left( 1/4\right)\right]^2 }{4\sqrt{2\pi}}-1
\end{align}
This classical integral can be found for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1565017).

Putting all the results together gives
\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n\binom{2n}{n}}{4^{n}(2n+1)(2n-1)(4n+1)}=-\frac{\pi}{8}+\frac{\left[\Gamma\left( 1/4\right)\right]^2 }{12\sqrt{2\pi}}
\end{equation} 
which is also identical to the result given by @ChipHurst in the comments.

Comment: Excellent work!

Comment: Thanks @clathratus